# The "lower part" of $BV$ function is always lower semi-continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

Let $u\in BV(\Omega)$ be a function of *bounded variation*, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^N$ is open bounded smooth boundary. Define 
$$
u^-(x):=\sup\left\{t\in\mathbb R:\,\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal L^N(B(x,r)\cap\{u<t\})}{r^N}=0\right\}.
$$
Then $u^-$ is $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. well defined.

My question: do we have $u^-$ is lower semi-continuous? In one dimension this is true. But what about multi-dimensions?

PS: by lower semi-continuous we mean for any $x_n\to x$, we have 
$$
\liminf_{n\to \infty} u^-(x_n)\geq u^-(x)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider $u(x)=\chi_E(x)$ where $E$ is a set which has an inner cusp, for instance the subset of $\mathbb R^2$ given by
$$E=\left\{(x_1,x_2):\,x_2< \sqrt{|x_1|}\right\}. $$
Then $u$, restricted to a bounded open set, is BV,  and $u^-(x)=u(x)$ for every $x$ except for the origin, in which $u^-(0)=1$, therefore lower semicontinuity fails for example along the sequence $(0,\frac1n)$.

Comment: but $u^-$ is only $\mathcal H^1$ a.e. defined right? So for counterexample we may need to have some functions which has the property you mentioned on a line or something. But I am not sure whether those function is still in $BV$.

Comment: From what I understand $u^-$ is defined where the expressions make sense, which is everywhere in this case. Moreover it does not depend on the Lebesgue representative. Otherwise how do you define lower semicontinuity for a function which is defined only $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-a.e.?

Comment: @spatially Maybe you're referring to something like this: given any BV function, $u^-$ is well defined outside of a $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-negligible set. But it could well be that the latter is empty, not just negligible, as in the example.

Comment: Let me think about what you wrote here.

Comment: A cusp doesn't sound like a very smooth boundary to me.

Comment: @Renart the cusp is not on the boundary, it is on the BV function itself (more precisely on the set of which it's the characteristic function). As $\Omega$ we can take the ball $B(0,1)$.